# How to find the indexes of matches in two lists

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I'm currently stuck in trying to find a nice solution for the following list comprehension question:

It's easy to find equal values with the same index in two lists, e.g.

```
>>> vec1 = [3,2,1,4,5,6,7]
>>> vec2 = [1,2,3,3,5,6,9]
>>> [a for a, b in zip(vec1, vec2) if a == b]
[2,5,6]
```

However, I just need the indexes in the lists where these matches occur, not the values itself. Using the above example, the output I want is: `[1,4,5]`

I tinkered around but I could only think of a "multi-line" solution. Does anybody know how I could find the indexes in a more Pythonic manner?

Comment: What are you planning to do with the indexes?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: Good question. Are you mathematician?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were close, use `enumerate()` here.

`enumerate()` returns a tuple where first element is the index and second element is the data fetched from the iterable.

```
In [169]: vec1 = [3,2,1,4,5,6,7]

In [170]: vec2 = [1,2,3,3,5,6,9]

In [171]: [i for i,(a, b) in enumerate(zip(vec1, vec2)) if a == b]
Out[171]: [1, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[i for i, (a,b) in enumerate(zip(vec1,vec2)) if a==b]
```